# Community Templates (Napili) customization

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community

I'm testing winter 17 templates, I like to understand how much customization we can do with new community templates/builder/lightning,

1. It seems the home page can't be changed, since its not editable
2. Header seems not customizable other than editing labels/changing color

Ideally I like to roll out my own template with everything customizable with lightning components and still use new community builder in some fashion

Also I see lightning components are not supported in old visualforce template based communities, is it still true ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Custom Themes as part of Napili Template to completely change the look and feel of the Home Page. Please refer to the following link to learn more about how to create custom themes using Lightning Components.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm

Comment: Thanks!, it works for napili template, but when I create custom template, it doesn't show up  under theme selection. Also is there way to override home page with community builder page ?

Comment: You need to implement forceCommunity:themeLayout in your Lightning Component.

Comment: There is a sample theme layout in the documentation in this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm

Comment: I tried this, still not showing up in theme selector or changing template area https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_layouts.htm